# Loading a *.cshtml page in JavaScript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-events

I have to load a `*.cshtml` partial page in my layout page after a link is clicked. How it can be done in JavaScript/jQuery or Razor/MVC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use a Partial with Child Action

example

```
[ChildActionOnly]
ActionResult _Partial()
{

  return PartialView();
}
```

then the easiest way to do this would be to designate a div (`divPartial`) in your layout

```
<div id="divPartial"></div>
```

Within your View, href event, and use the JQuery load method.

```
<a href="#" id="aLink">click me</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#aLink').click(function() {
      $('#divPartial').load('@Url.ActionLink("_Partial","Controller")');
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: @Fakharuzzaman, if this answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking the check under it